# angularjs : setting class attribute in a directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to set the class attribute of my directive. That's how I do it:

the relevant code in the directive

```
template: '<input class="myClass" />'

scope:{
 myClass = '@'
}
```

and that's how I call it

```
<my-directive my-class="someClass" />
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens. No errors, but the class is just not set.

Anything I'm missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

myClass is a scope variable in your new isolated scope. You have to write `template: '<input class="{{myClass}}" />` or `template: '<input ng-class="myClass" />`

Comment: nice one. I had missed that. Thanks !