# Add class to input parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to add class to input parent if input is not empty or focus because I want to change label position.

```
<div class="input-field">
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
</div>
```

I can do this:

```
<div class="input-field" ng-class="{ active: signIn.email.$viewValue.length > 0 || isFocus }">
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" ng-focus="isFocus=true" ng-blur="isFocus=false" required />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
</div>
```

But I have many inputs and my code will be very large and ugly.

How can I do it better?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with attribute directive where you can have logic which class you need to add to input-filed.

```
angular.directive('myClass', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',   
    link: function (scope, element,attr) {
      // your logic
    }
  };

or 
$scope.myClass = "";
<div class="input-field" ng-class="myClass" />
```

[angularjs : setting class attribute in a directive template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198995/angularjs-setting-class-attribute-in-a-directive-template)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scope variable for this.

```js
myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myController",['$scope',function($scope){
         
         var someCondition  =  2 > 1;
         $scope.myClass = {
               active : someCondition ? "active" : "not-so-active"
           
         }
  
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<div class="input-field" ng-class="{{myClass}}">
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" ng-focus="focus=true" ng-blur="focus=false" required />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
</div>
  </div>
```